# spacy pandas pycaret compatibility issues

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, spacy, pycaret

*I'm adding this question because the internet had no answer. I'll answer it here.
(google searching the error message led to only 2 pages, neither helpful, hopefully this is 3)*

When trying to

`python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm`

I got the following error message:

`numpy.ndarray size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 88 from C header, got 80 from PyObject`

All subsequent error messages were misleading.
the solution that solved it was to downgrade spacy

`pip install spacy==2.3.0`

Answer (score 1):

Downgrade spacy
 `pip install spacy==2.3.0`